# How to send all roles a member has in a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to send a message where the bot shows all roles a user has. I just want to, that the bot mentions the roles in the message. Here's the code I'm using:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def whois(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
        if user:
            roles = user.roles
            embed = discord.Embed(
                description = user.mention
            )
            embed.add_field(name='Roles', value=roles)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_author(name=user.name, icon_url=user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

This is what I'm getting in the message:

```
[<Role id=785571867279753238 name='@everyone'>, <Role id=787317902906490940 name='admin'>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit of list comprehension to get the mentions, then you can use the `str.join(list)` method to get a string

```py
mentions_list = [role.mention for role in roles]
mentions = "\n".join(mentions_list) # Using newline as the delimiter
```

Or if you want a one-liner

```py
mentions = "\n".join([role.mention for role in roles]) # Using newline as the delimiter
```

EDIT

```py
mentions = "\n".join([role.mention if role.name != "@everyone" else role.name for role in roles])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but how can i remove the extra @ in @everyone? Or much better, remove @everyone from the list

Comment: You can have a simple ternary expression in the list comprehension, let me edit my answer

Comment: Now I got one question left, how can I sort the roles like the hirache? It's always starting with the lowest at the top and ending with the highest one. The documentation says that this is normal, but is there a way to change it?

Comment: This is not really related to your question, they're also sorted by default. The list comprehension might have put it in reversed order, you can simply reverse the list with the `reversed` function